# Why I am getting this output?output = 012345

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 

void main()
{
    int i;                         
    for ( ;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d",i);
    }
}
```

Why I am getting this output? output = 012345

1. I did not expecting any output. because as i didnt intilise i, so from where he is going to start?
2. if i will be intilise by a undefined value, why I am getting the same output as many times i run the code?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Using `i` (which isn't declared) should lead to a compilation failure at `printf ("%d", i);` - Unrelated: Instead of `void main()`, make it `int main(void)` to make it portable.

Comment: Note that you never initialized `I`. You're lucky you got any output at all.

Comment: I noticed that you edited the question but you missed one of the most important things when asking a question: Describing what you expect the program to do!

Answer (score 1):

- ```c
  int i;
  ```

  `i` is uninitialized and holds an indeterminate value. `0` is one of the many values it can contain.
- ```c
  for ( ;i<=5;i++)
  ```

  In both `i<=5` and `i++` you read `i` that has an indeterminate value. The compiler is allowed to assume that you never do that and may produce assembler code that does *anything*. The program therefore has what is called *undefined behavior*.
- ```c
  printf ("%d",i);
  ```

  Here you print `i` whatever it may be. **If** `i` happened to contain `0` when you left it uninitialized - and **if** the compiler was "kind" enough to let your failure to initialize `i` through without producing an executable that crashes (or worse), then the loop will step `i` from `0` to `6`. When it reaches `6`, the condition, `i<=5`, will be `false` and the loop will end. Only for the values when `i` is less than, or equal to, `5` will `printf ("%d",i);` be reached.

Note that the program may do different things when you run it multiple times because it has undefined behavior. `i` may suddenly be `-98723849` when you run  the program and then your loop will print the values from `-98723849` up to `5`.

> I did not expecting any output. because as i didnt intilise i, so from where he is going to start?

As mentioned - the program could do just about anything because you didn't initialize `i` and then read from it. In your case, it seems `i` contained a `0` and that the program appears to behave as-if you initialized it to `0`. Again, this is "pure luck" - no matter how many times in a row it displays the same behavior.

> if i will be intilise by a undefined value, why I am getting the same output as many times i run the code?

Because the program has undefined behavior. It may repeat the same thing over and over again for many years. It's a ticking bomb that may suddenly explode one day.

Comment: Note that the program may do different things when you run it multiple times because it has undefined behavior.                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                               
but I am getting the same output as many times i run the code.

Comment: @ParasChandravanshi If you're getting the same output every time, what are you saying?  Are you disagreeing with Ted when he said that the program may do different things every time?  As it happens, he is right, and you are wrong.  He did not say, the program *must* do different things every time.

Comment: @ParasChandravanshi Yes, getting the same result is also possible with _undefined behavior_. You can't be sure though. One day it may crash or print something else. You want to correct the mistake so that the behavior of the program is defined.

Comment: @ParasChandravanshi Suppose you live in a small town.  Suppose that every morning, at 3 am, you go "downtown" to your town's one stoplight.  You wait until the light is *red*, and cross the street.  You do this 100 nights in a row.  You never get hit by a car.  From this do you conclude, "Crossing the intersection against a red light is safe."?  From this do you conclude, "People who say you can't cross when the light is red are wrong."?

Comment: @ Steve Summit ok steve I understood.

Comment: @ParasChandravanshi Does the answer answer your questions?

Comment: The answer covers this, but just to be clear for OP: the moment that the comparison `i <= 5` is attempted, the program is invalid due to undefined behavior. Since `i` is uninitialized, it has an indeterminate value, and it is undefined behavior to attempt to use an indeterminate value.